# Trouble uploading a big zip file in Laravel

Tags: php, file, laravel, upload, zip

I have 3 inputs (2 text inputs and 1 file input). All inputs is required.

When I upload a zip file (13MB). I do not get any data from 3 inputs so the validation failed.

I try reduce the file size (6MB) then it's OK.

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: I think know the answer to your question. Is this happen in your local env ? What OS are you using ? Are you using WAMP ?

Comment: My OS is MAC and I'm using Homestead. I try run in hosting but it's not work.

Comment: Edit you php ini, and you should be all set. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 13M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 13M
```

Rather than 13M, I suggest you set it to a little bit bigger like 50 MB.

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

If you can't change your php.ini, you're out of luck.  You cannot change these values at run-time; uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will have failed by the time execution reaches your call to `ini_set`.

See the [Description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).